# Different threads using the same instance of DbContext

Tags: multithreading, .net-core, dbcontext

Good afternoon!
I have 2 projects in different solutions. One is made with netcore and the other with net framework. Both in C#.
What I want to do is call an api from the net framework project. To do this, I use this call:

```
response = await client.PostAsync(urlInterfacePrefix
                  + "EmptyComponentAndSendToRefractory?ladle=" + h.Name
                  + "&user=" + user
                  + "&sectorPP=" + sectorPP
                  + "&userPP=" + userPP
                  + "&hostPP=" + hostPP
                  , content);
```

Where in the variable url Interface Prefix I have all the prefix of the api call. The thing is that when I run it, the first time I call the method it works fine, but the second and the following ones no longer. It throws me the following error:

> A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed. This is usually caused by different threads using the same instance of DbContext.

I thought about instantiating the DbContext but it loads itself in the startup.cs as follows:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<CoreDbContext>(
        options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("CoreConnection"), b => b.MigrationsAssembly("MOM.Core.WebAPI")).EnableSensitiveDataLogging());

    IMapper mapper = MappingConfig.RegisterMaps().CreateMapper();
    services.AddSingleton(mapper);
            
    services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
    services.AddControllers();
      
    AddSwagger(services);
}
```

This is the constructor:

```
private readonly CoreDbContext _db; 
private IMapper _mapper; 
protected ResponseDto _response; 
private HutOperation _hutOperation; 
public static List<OMM.Sector> _sectores = null; 
private Mutex mutex_process_message = new Mutex(); 
public TransferLadleRepository(CoreDbContext db, IMapper mapper)
{ 
    _db = db; 
    _mapper = mapper; 
    _hutOperation = new HutOperation(db);
    _response = new ResponseDto(); 
}
```

What would be the correct way to solve it?

Comment: How is `TransferLadleRepository` registered?

Comment: what are you talking about? Can you be more specific please?

Comment: I mean, how is it registered in your dependency injection? Or if it's not registered, how is it created?

Comment: It is a simple class that I placed in a folder called "Repository" and whose constructor is the one that I show above.

Comment: How is the constructor called?